# Dark status bar icons when Dialog is open

Tags: android, dialog, statusbar

I have an activity with this style:

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
</style>
```

It shows dark status bar icons, but when I show a dialog, the icons turn the color to light.

The style of my dialog is:

```
<style name="CustomStyleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/round_corner_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
</style>
```

What I need to change to keep the icons always dark?

This is my manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.FirstActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomStyle" />
<activity
        android:name=".dialogs.FirstDialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CustomStyleDialog" />
```

Dialog builders (CustomDatepicker is a class extends DatePickerDialog)

DatePicker

```
private void showDatePickerDialog(Date starDate, int titleResId) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(starDate);
    CustomDatePicker datePickerDialog = new CustomDatePicker(this, this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.setTitle(titleResId);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Alert

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.delete_title)
    .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_confirmation))
    .show();
```

Comment: Can I see your AlertDialog BUilder code?

Comment: Question edited with the builder code

Comment: Try to change your parent inn theme to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"` in CustomStyleDialog

Comment: it does not solve the problem

Comment: Okay instead of: `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` try `new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))`

Comment: I've come across situations like this before and in most cases these 2 solutions solved my issue..

Answer (score 2):

I think you need dark icons only, use below example code

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert_dark)
    .setTitle(R.string.confirm_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.confirm_text)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();    
        }
```

replace this `android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert_dark` with dark icon you want

Comment: This change the status bar icons to dark? cant find ic_dialog_alert_dark

Comment: you can set icon following this https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/android_vector_assets.html or u can upload drawable what u want and set it as an icon

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring for me, in Android 10 devices specifically.

One way to override it would be to make the dialog parent theme **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark**

Note: This will make the text and background of dialog dark, in case you are default color. might want to override them yourself.